# How to generate avi video from images?

Tags: java

I need to create a video from text input. I have successfully generated image from text input.

Now i need to generate a video of avi format from the above created image.

How can i do this?

Comment: What research have you done already? Asking StackOverflow should *not* be the first thing you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ffmpeg it is free and run on cmd line. on cmd line with ffmpeg cmd and input images as arugemnts and set some params and it will do your job.

Comment: +1 for good output format.  I started with hopes of finding a native library in java, and started with a demo http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/ that was built on JFM and can theoretically make quicktime and avi output files, but even though the output was playable on my machine using quicktime, no one else could see anything but black.  The advantage of ffmpeg is that the mp4 format, for instance, is viewable by almost everyone without any additional special codecs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2008/08/writing-avi-videos-in-pure-java/

This was the second hit when asking google for "Java create AVI".